# Giant set of strings leads to memory error - alternative?

Tags: python

I'm trying to create a really huge list of incrementing 9 digits numbers (worst case). My plan is to have something like this:

```
['000000001', '000000002' , ..............,'999999999']
```

I already wrote the code. However, as soon as I run the code, my console prints `"Memory Error"` message.

Here is my current code:

```
HUGE_LIST = [''.join(i) for i in product('012345678', repeat = 9)
```

I know this might not be the best code to produce the list. Thus, can someone help me find a better way to solve this memory issue?

I'm planning to use HUGE_LIST for comparison with user input.

Example: a user enters '12345678' as input, then I want my code to assert that input with the HUGE_LIST.

Comment: What do you need this for? You might try writing to a file instead.

Comment: @Ahmad it is a simple game that I'm trying to create. I prefer not to use a file tho.

Comment: How are you using this?  If you're just iterating through it, you can use a generator `(''.join(i) for i in product('012345678', repeat = 9))` to avoid building the entire list in memory

Comment: @PatrickHaugh I'm planning to use it later for comparison with user input. For example, if a user enters '12345678' as input, then my code will check from that HUGE_LIST whether user input exists or not.

Comment: You could also use `list(range(1000000000))` instead of `product()` and convert the numeric values to stings on the fly as needed. Storing integer values should require less memory that the strings do.

Comment: No need to go through all this trouble then.  Just check that `len(your_input)` is the correct length and that `your_input.isdigit()` is true

Comment: @PatrickHaugh sorry but this is part of the game :( I have to compare it with this HUGE LIST

Comment: Why does it have to be a part of the game? I refuse to believe that an assignment would require you to do it this way.

Comment: Can you convert the input to an integer so you only need to store integers in your `HUGE_LIST`? So you're still checking to see if the input is in the list, just storing the list more efficiently.

Answer (score 0):

The best way to solve an issue like this is to avoid a memory-intensive algorithm entirely. In this case, since your goal is to test whether a particular string is in the list, just write a function that checks whether the string satisfies the criteria to be in the list. For example, if your list contains all sequences of 9 digits, then your function just has to check whether a given input is a sequence of 9 digits.

```
def check(string):
    return len(string) == 9 and all(c.isdigit() for c in string)
```

(in practice, give it a better name than `check`). Or if you want all sequences of 9 digits in which none of them is a `9`, as your current code defining `HUGE_LIST` suggests, you could write

```
def check(string):
    return len(string) == 9 and all(c.isdigit() and c != '9' for c in string)
```

Or so on.

If you can't write an algorithm to decide whether a string (or whatever) is in the list or not, the next best thing is to make a generator that will produce the values one at a time. If you already have a list comprehension, like

```
HUGE_LIST = [<something> for <variable> in <expression>]
```

then you can turn that into a generator by replacing the square brackets with parentheses:

```
HUGE_GENERATOR = (<something> for <variable> in <expression>)
```

Then you can test for membership using `string in HUGE_GENERATOR`. Note that after doing so, `HUGE_GENERATOR` will be (at least partially) consumed, so you can't use it for another membership test; you will have to recreate it if you want to test again.